# Unable to deploy firebase project to custom domain

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

- Took a free domain on freenom
- Linked it successfully with a project on firebase
- Added a target name to the domain
- Added the target to
  [firebase.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TukK.png)
- on running `firebase deploy`
  [Error : HTTP Error 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3zPM.png)

Could someone point out what i'm doing wrong cause I followed all the steps on the firebase website but still am unable to get it running. The HTML file I want to host just has a H1 tag with "Hello World".

Comment: If you have a problem with deployment, please contact Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/

Answer (score 3):

You do not require any special steps to deploy the site on custom website. Once your site is up on the default domain. Then the website gets automatically replicated on you connected custom domain. Hope this helps you.

**This is my firebase.json file:**

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. I didn't understand how firebase worked then and messed my the project. Now, I understand.

Comment: @abhishek can you share some official link that says that. as in i thought in a project different domains could have different code hosted on them